# Win7 x64 Bluecove

Tags: java, bluetooth, windows-7-x64, bluecove

I'm trying to use Bluecove for an application I'm writing. Version 2.1 of the jar didn't work, so a little Google showed me that it had always had issues with x64, so I turned to the latest 2.1.1 "snapshot", and I still get that the bluecove_x64 dll is missing. Am I doing something wrong, or should I just look for another API?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem after installing a vendor's bluetooth stack and management utilities.  My java app which used bluetooth worked fine before this, after the install I got the bluecove_x64.dll not found error.  After much searching, I reverted to an earlier system checkpoint (before I tried installing the "newer" bluetooth) and all was back to normal.

On another system, the toshiba bluetooth software had already been installed.  I did a system checkpoint (in case the following was to not work), then went into the device manager, and uninstalled every "device" under bluetooth.  Be sure to check the "delete driver software" box too, or they will come right back.

After this, the bluetooth device will appear to be gone.  Go to the top of the tree, right click, and do "scan for hardware changes".  This *should* install the Microsoft generic bluetooth drives which then work (for me) just fine on Win7_x64.  If this doesn't install them, then you may try searching for a download, or another stack.